# Defining variables across Subs (w/in module) in VBA

Tags: excel, vba, variables

Would like to define reference variables (calls a value from a cell in the sheet using ActiveSheet.Cells[row, col]) in one location in a module, for use across multiple subs in an MS Excel file. The file is an action tracker, the subs automate some of the emailing (each subs opens emails under given conditions). All reference variables are the same for each sub - defining in one place will make maintaining the spreadsheet much simpler.

Tried to define variables above first sub, error message appears on first value (as detailed below). I've searched (a) Global Variables and (b) how to define above the subs. However (a) variables all in the same module (b) error message as detailed below. I haven't located a guide on defining variables using ActiveSheet.Cells() references.

```
Option Explicit
'Defines variables for all macros:

'Defining Reference Variables
Today = ActiveSheet.Cells(2, 4)
ActionLogTitle = ActiveSheet.Cells(3, 3)
IPT_Leader = ActiveSheet.Cells(7, 7)
```

(On `Today = ActiveSheet.Cells(2,4)` error highlights on "2")

> Compile error:
>   Invalid outside procedure

Comment: The error message is pretty straightforward. Those lines can only be *within* a procedure (`Sub` or `Function`) - note, if that cell just has today's date, then you can use `Date` within VBA.

Comment: Look into how to pass parameters before you try to define and use globals. `Today` is redundant, and the other two very likely need to be read off a very specific worksheet, not just whatever sheet happens to be active at that time. Consider making `ActionLogTitle` and `IPT_Leader` (without the underscore) properties (`Public Property Get` procedures) of the specific sheet they belong to.

Answer (score 5):

As the compiler is hinting, you cannot write assignments outside of a Sub/Function.

You can declare a function for each variable:

```
Function MyValue()
    MyValue = ActiveSheet.Cells(2, 4).Value
End Function
```

Ideally you don't use ActiveSheet unless that's really what you want though.

Comment: Sorry - I don't know what you mean in that comment.

Answer (score 4):

There are a lot of ways to define today, but using a word, which is used by Excel English formula `=TODAY()`, is probably a discussable idea (although it will work!). In general, consider declaring the variable like this somewhere in the modules:

```
Public myToday as Date
```

Then, you may reset it everytime the worksheet is openned:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    myToday = Date
    'or 
    myToday = Worksheets("Name").Range("D2").Value
End Sub
```

Anyway, working with `Public` variables is in general discouraged in any programming language, thus it is probably a better idea to come up with a dedicated function or class for it.

Comment: Note, the word `Today` is not part of the Excel object model.

Comment: I honestly would remove that sentence (up to you, but I don't see how formula nomenclature has bearing on variable declaration in VBA). `Date` is a formula too :) But to be honest, the `Today` might not be the best example for an answer, as it is redundant, as pointed out in [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58490190/defining-variables-across-subs-w-in-module-in-vba#comment103311149_58490190).

Comment: @BigBen - with me, I always have to check which one does which - `Date()`, `Now()`, `Time()`, `Today()`, as far as in different languages these are different, thus I avoid using them as variable names. But I guess this is me...

Comment: I figured that it was a language issue - but I think @Mathieu Guindon's comment that a `Today` global is redundant is spot on. After all, that is what `Date` is. EDIT: "Discussable idea", ha. What a revision :) Brought a smile to my face, though I'm probably done discussing it haha.

Comment: `Today` being redundant is because there's already a `Today` function in global scope that returns ...today's date. Hence, a `Today` variable that holds today's date is redundant... unless we're talking about some `IDateTimeProvider` interface with a `Today` member that abstracts away the current date/time for testability purposes... but I doubt that's the case here.

Comment: @MathieuGuindon noteworthy comment! The original text I replied to was "using a word, which is used by the Excel VBA library." - note I don't see `VBA.DateTime.Today`, am I missing something? https://i.stack.imgur.com/00dLE.png. Immediate window > `? Today` - returns a blank string. What am I missing here? I am familiar with the use of `Date`.

Comment: @BigBen argh I always get this `DateTime` stuff wrong! Indeed, there's no `VBA.DateTime.Today`, that would be `VBA.DateTime.Date`. So, `Today` isn't hiding anything (but that doesn't make it any less redundant)

Comment: But... your original comment that I referenced still stands, because `Date` is just fine :) Yep, agreed on the redundancy, which is why I pushed for a different variable example in this answer. Or... maybe the answer should be removed entirely, as it basically says, "Don't use global variables, even though I just gave you an example how to." :)